# pytest reports too much on assert failures

Tags: python, pytest, verbosity

Is there a way for pytest to only output a single line assert errors?

This problem arises when you have modules with asserts, If those asserts fails, it dumps the entire function that failed the asserts.

```
> assert r.status_code == 200, f"{idtest.tools.now()} wrong status code {r.status_code}: resp:{r.text}"
E AssertionError: 2019-06-11 12:41:17.239128 wrong status code 500: resp:{"timestamp":"2019-06-11T10:41:17.187+0000","status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","message":"The user was not found","path":"/mid/business"}
```

In this case the idtest.testapi.midbusiness() is shown entirely in the pytest output.

Comment: `pytest --tb={auto,long,short,line,native,no}`. E.g. `pytest --tb=no` will not print any trace at all.

Comment: @hoefling, --tb=short gives me exaclty what I want

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Adjust the traceback print mode (`--tb`):

```
$ pytest --help
  --tb=style            traceback print mode (auto/long/short/line/native/no).
```

E.g. `pytest --tb=no` will not print any trace at all.