# pytest failure with no traceback or showing code

Tags: pytest

i want to change the behavior of pytest failure. i don't want to see a code or any trace back in the failure summery. i just want it to show the assertion statement and that is all. how i can do that

for instance if i have

```
assert x==y , pytest.fail("fail message")
```

i want the test to fail with the "fail message" and with no traceback
i usually workaround unexpected exception with logging the errors and exit , but i am not sure how to handle the pytest assertion

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pytest reports too much on assert failures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56542216/pytest-reports-too-much-on-assert-failures)

Comment: thx it was a lead to an answer